# AlertBox at back press in android

Tags: android

i would like to show alertbox while user press back on phone.
so simply i use ::

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            try {
                  AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertbox.setMessage("This is the alertbox!");
                    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    // set a negative/no button and create a listener
                    alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'No' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    alertbox.show();
          stopService(new Intent(this, BackServices.class));
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

***`but problem is`*** : when i press back alertbox show but it exit from application. i want stop exit from application until  user press yes button.if user press no then get back to application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are two things to make it possible

**1.)**

```
stopService(new Intent(this, BackServices.class));
                finish();
```

Remove `finish();` from here, as it is the reason your activity gets close

**2.)** Instead of

```
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

you can return false like this,

```
  return false;
```

Comment: now can you tell me how can i make alert box colourful or some attractive

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539976/how-can-i-optimize-this-dialog-code-for-android

Answer (score 1):

My approach will be like this,

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
    //finish();
     AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alertbox.setTitle("Warning");
     alertbox.setMessage("Exit Application?");
     alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new
     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
     finish();
     }
     });
     alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new
     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

     }
     });
     alertbox.show();
}
```

Or considering your own code, I might do something like this.

You have to provide finish() inside positive button click event like this,

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        try {
              AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertbox.setMessage("This is the alertbox!");
                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         stopService(new Intent(this, BackServices.class));
                              finish();
                    }
                });

                // set a negative/no button and create a listener
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'No' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                alertbox.show();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: when i press back key, dialogue are shown at the second moment it will close application as well as dialogue without press any button

Comment: I have made a little change to my answer. try it now

Comment: I believe that's how we track back press event normally and will work fine without issues

Comment: I am sorry then. That's the working solution for me. maybe you are doing some mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
Keep your code as it is...with adding finish() call in positive button click
And override onBackPressed() method with doing nothin

public void onBackPressed() {

}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        try {
              AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertbox.setMessage("This is the alertbox!");
                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         stopService(new Intent(this, BackServices.class));
                              finish();
                    }
                });

                // set a negative/no button and create a listener
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'No' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                alertbox.show();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution will be to return `true` to indicate that you have consumed the event.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        // do your stuff
        ....
        ....
        return true;  // control will return from here. super will not be called.
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```